# Error al intentar cargar un fichero csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, anaconda

Con el siguiente script, recupero el directorio de trabajo actual y cambio a otro directorio contenido en el directorio actual. Asimismo iprimo los nombres de los archivos contenidos en dicho subdirectorio.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd
os.chdir("./Ficheros")
os.listdir(".")

['EPSV_EP2_r4.xlsx',
 'Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.xlsx',
 'Nexus_ES0173268006_r4.csv',
 'EPSV_EP2_r4.csv',
 'Avantage_ES0112231008_r4.csv',
 'ValorRelativo_ES0128522002_r4.xlsx',
 'DedaloPP_F1467_r4.xlsx',
 'Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.csv',
 'NexusPP_F1605_r4.csv',
 'Nexus_ES0173268006_r4.xlsx',
 'TrueValue_ES0180792006_r4.xlsx',
 'Avantage_ES0112231008_r4.xlsx',
 'ValorRelativo_ES0128522002_r4.csv',
 'TrueValue_ES0180792006_r4.csv',
 'DedaloPP_F1467_r4.csv',
 'NexusPP_F1605_r4.xlsx']
```

¿Por qué este script que muestro a continuación, no encuentra el fichero solicitado y me da el error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Ficheros'"?.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd
os.chdir("./Ficheros")
os.listdir(".")

df = pd.read_csv("Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True, usecols = ["Date", "Close"], 
                 na_values = ["nan"])
df[:3]
```

Agradeceré vuestras sugerencias.

Comment: ¿Cómo lanzas ese script? Quizás lo estás lanzando desde un IDE, o un editor, o un Notebook Jupyter, y entonces quizás no estás en la carpeta que creías ¿Has verificado que la salida de `cwd` te sale igual en ambos casos? (usa `print(cwd)`)

Comment: Tu sugerencia me ayudó a reflexionar y encontrar el fallo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema radicaba en que los ficheros csv que intenta leer la función, utilizan la coma para los decimales en lugar del punto, que es el que read_csv asume por defecto.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True, decimal = ",", usecols = ["Date", "Close"], na_values = ["nan"], sep="\t")
```

Comment: Me alegro de que resolvieras tu problema, pero entonces la pregunta no estaba bien planteada, ya que el separador dentro del CSV no puede producirte el error `No such file or directory: './Ficheros'"` que mencionabas.

Comment: He vuelto a comprobarlo. Si no pongo  decimal =","  y  sep =/t" me retorna       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: './Ficheros'

Answer (score 0):

la instruccion os.chdir("./Ficheros") lo que hace a nivel de sistema operativo es cambiarte de directorio al directorio ./Ficheros

Cuando haces os.chdir() y no existe es por que en el directorio actual donde ejecutas el script de python no existe un directorio ./Ficheros

lo ideal serial

```
for file in os.listdir("./Ficheros"):
    pd.read_csv(file)
```